# If 16 million kilometers were added to Earth's semi-major axis, what measurable effect would there be on Mars' orbit?

Tags: gravity, orbital-mechanics, mars, planetary-science, newtonian-gravity

I have some education in astronomy, but nothing extensive in astrophysics. I can follow mathematical procedure with assistance. Procedural responses are most welcome!

Comment: Thank you for helping, Justin!

Comment: Gravitational forces never go to zero even at large distances; basically "everything affects everything" (at least within observable universe, but let's not go down [that rabbit hole](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44989/7982) quite yet\) so the answer to "would there be any effect" is always "Yes!" when it comes to this kind of question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, even pluto makes the other planets wobble by an Àngstrom/Micron. Gravity radiates and is rarified through space like light from a lightsource.